# Conditional formatting comparing two fields in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm comparing numbers I calculate to values already in a DB so I can point out what entries in the DB need updating.

To make this easy to find, I'd like to color the data in the DB column bright yellow if it's different. So far, all fails.

First attempt:

```
        With Range("M" & i).FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=K" & i
        End With
        Range("M" & i).FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

All cells turn yellow. But it's not clear what the problem is - can I use xlCellValue and compare that to another cell? Or is the problem that the values are off by the 5th decimal or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I typed this into the next cell over…
=M19=K18
and the system returned "TRUE"

Comment: I have since tried this: 

 With Range("M" & i).FormatConditions
   .Add Type:=xlFormula, Formula1:="=$K$" & i & "<>$M$" & i
  End With
  Range("M" & i).FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

This also fails, all cells are yellow. The absolute addressing was suggested by a bug report on MS.

Comment: And now I seem to have found the cause, but not the solution. When I enter the formula-based version by hand in the editor, it works fine. But when I attempt to enter the same string in VBA and then examine it in the editor, it's different. Instead of it being formula based, XL thinks it's a TOP 10 VALUES condition! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

OMG. This works…

```
        With Range("M" & i).FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEquals, Formula1:="=$K$" & i & "<>$M$" & i
        End With
        Range("M" & i).FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

It was the Type:=